# GDI+ / C#: How to save an image as EMF?

Tags: c#, gdi+, .emf

If you use Image.Save Method to save an image to a EMF/WMF, you get an exception (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx)

Is there another way to save the image to an EMF/WMF?
Are there any encoders available?

Answer (score 24):

`Image` is an abstract class: what you want to do depends on whether you are dealing with a `Metafile` or a `Bitmap`.

Creating an image with GDI+ and saving it as an EMF is simple with `Metafile`. Per Mike's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf/152830#152830):

```
var path = @"c:\foo.emf"
var g = CreateGraphics(); // get a graphics object from your form, or wherever
var img = new Metafile(path, g.GetHdc()); // file is created here
var ig = Graphics.FromImage(img);
// call drawing methods on ig, causing writes to the file
ig.Dispose(); img.Dispose(); g.ReleaseHdc(); g.Dispose();
```

This is what you want to do most of the time, since that is what EMF is for: saving vector images in the form of GDI+ drawing commands.

You can save a `Bitmap` to an EMF file by using the above method and calling `ig.DrawImage(your_bitmap)`, but be aware that this does not magically covert your raster data into a vector image.

Comment: Wonderful, I had completely overlooked this easy way of creating a metafile based on the Metafile constructor. I must admit that having to pass in an original HDC is a bit confusing, but nevertheless, it is working.

Comment: Wow, this really works! Amazing!! This should have been accepted!

Answer (score 12):

If I remember correctly, it can be done with a combination of the Metafile.GetHenhmetafile(), the API GetEnhMetaFileBits() and Stream.Write(), something like

```
[DllImport("gdi32")] static extern uint GetEnhMetaFileBits(IntPtr hemf, uint cbBuffer, byte[] lpbBuffer);


IntPtr h = metafile.GetHenhMetafile();
int size = GetEnhMetaFileBits(h, 0, null);
byte[] data = new byte[size];
GetEnhMetaFileBits(h, size, data);
using (FileStream w = File.Create("out.emf")) {
    w.Write(data, 0, size);
}
// TODO: I don't remember whether the handle needs to be closed, but I guess not.
```

I think this is how I solved the problem when I had it.

Comment: While it looks like this should work I'm finding that it outputs the rasterized version of the metafile, not the vector GDI records.  Additionally, you need to call DeleteEnhMetaFile(h) and be aware that calling GetHenhMetaFile() puts the metafile object into an invalid state.

Comment: You need to call DeleteEnhMetafile(h) when you are done, and the Metafile object is put into an invalid state by the GetHenhMetafile call.

If the Metafile is a raster based metafile this will give you a raster based .emf on disk.  If it is a vector based metafile, then you will get a vector based .emf on disk.  Typically calling metafile.Save("filename", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf) will give you a .png file.

Answer (score 3):

A metafile is a file which records a sequence of GDI operations. It is scalable because the original sequence of operations that generated the picture are captured, and therefore the co-ordinates that were recorded can be scaled.

I think, in .NET, that you should create a `Metafile` object, create a `Graphics` object using `Graphics.FromImage`, then perform your drawing steps. The file is automatically updated as you draw on it. You can find a small sample in the documentation for [Graphics.AddMetafileComment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.addmetafilecomment.aspx).

If you really want to store a bitmap in a metafile, use these steps then use `Graphics.DrawImage` to paint the bitmap. However, when it is scaled it will be stretched using `StretchBlt`.

Answer (score 3):

The question was: "Is there another way to save the image to an EMF/WMF?" Not "what is metafile" or "how to create metafile" or "how to use metafile with Graphics".

I also look for answer for this question "how to save EMF/WMF"
In fact if you use:

```
  Graphics grfx = CreateGraphics();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  IntPtr ipHdc = grfx.GetHdc();

  Metafile mf = new Metafile(ms, ipHdc);

  grfx.ReleaseHdc(ipHdc);
  grfx.Dispose();
  grfx = Graphics.FromImage(mf);

  grfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  grfx.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  grfx.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), 20, 20, 60, 60, 30, 120);
  grfx.Dispose();

  mf.Save(@"C:\file.emf", ImageFormat.Emf);
  mf.Save(@"C:\file.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

In both cases image is saved as format png. And this is the problem which I cannot solve :/

Comment: note that you need to use `System.Drawing.Imaging` for `Metafile` and `System.IO` for `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by erikkallen is correct. I tried this from VB.NET, and had to use 2 different DllImports to get it to work:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetEnhMetaFileBits")> _
    Public Shared Function GetEnhMetaFileBits(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()> ByVal hEMF As System.IntPtr, ByVal nSize As UInteger, ByVal lpData As IntPtr) As UInteger
End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetEnhMetaFileBits")> _
    Public Shared Function GetEnhMetaFileBits(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()> ByVal hEMF As System.IntPtr, ByVal nSize As UInteger, ByVal lpData() As Byte) As UInteger
End Function
```

The first import is used for the first call to get the emf size. The second import to get the actual bits.
Alternatively you could use:

```
Dim h As IntPtr = mf.GetHenhmetafile()
CopyEnhMetaFileW(h, FileName)
```

This copies the emf bits directly to the named file.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to close the `CopyEnhMetaFile` handler:

```
IntPtr ptr2 = CopyEnhMetaFile(iptrMetafileHandle, "image.emf");
DeleteEnhMetaFile(ptr2);

// Delete the metafile from memory
DeleteEnhMetaFile(iptrMetafileHandle);
```

Otherwise, you cannot delete the file because it's still used by the process.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to save the GDI instructions in a Metafile object to a EMF file. Han's post helped me solve the problem. This was before I joined SOF. Thank you, Han. Here is what [I tried](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=188&t=How_To_Convert_PDF_to_EMF_In_NET).

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CopyEnhMetaFile(  // Copy EMF to file
        IntPtr hemfSrc,   // Handle to EMF
        String lpszFile // File
    );

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int DeleteEnhMetaFile(  // Delete EMF
        IntPtr hemf // Handle to EMF
    );

   // Code that creates the metafile 
   // Metafile metafile = ...

   // Get a handle to the metafile
   IntPtr iptrMetafileHandle = metafile.GetHenhmetafile();

   // Export metafile to an image file
   CopyEnhMetaFile(
         iptrMetafileHandle, 
          "image.emf");

   // Delete the metafile from memory
   DeleteEnhMetaFile(iptrMetafileHandle);
```

Comment: If someone is having the same issue, I had to use `DeleteEnhMetaFile` on the IntPtr pointer returned by `CopyEnhMetaFile` in order to make sure that the saved imaged was not locked.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding such extern's and unmanaged cruft in a managed .NET app.
Instead, I'd recommend something a bit more like the managed solution given in this thread:

[Convert an image into WMF with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270763/convert-an-image-into-wmf-with-net)

P.S.  I am answering this old thread because this was the best answer I had found, but then ended up developing a managed solution, which then lead me to the link above.  So, to save others that time, I figured I'd point this one to that one.

Comment: thanks for the link, I had been searching for a solution for almost a week now...

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is much confusion over vector vs. bitmap. All of the code in this thread generates bitmap (non-vector) files - it does not preserve the vector GDI calls. To prove this to yourself, download the "EMF Parser" tool and inspect the output files: http://downloads.zdnet.com/abstract.aspx?docid=749645.

This issue has caused many developers considering anguish. Sure would be nice if Microsoft would fix this and properly support their own EMF format.

Comment: You are mistaken. user120789's answer, for instance, creates vector graphics.

Comment: -1: as 'reinierpost' mentioned, user120789's solution creates a vector graphic

Answer (score 0):

This is a public EMF class to save bitmap as EMF, but unfortunally, don't work .. return an error.

```
Public Class EMF
' This routine demonstrates how to create an Enhanced Metafile (EMF) from a
' bitmap image, contained in a PictureBox.
' You must use a PictureBox control, since the Image control doesn't support
' the hDC property, needed to create the image file.
' Draw a PictureBox on a form, and insert a supported image like Bmp,
' Jpg or Gif. Don't use a WMF or EMF image. Useful for imaging apps that need
' to save images to different formats than Bitmap.


' ========== API DECLARATIONS ==========

'Bitmap properties structure

Private Structure BITMAP
    Dim bmType As Long
    Dim bmWidth As Long
    Dim bmHeight As Long
    Dim bmWidthBytes As Long
    Dim bmPlanes As Integer
    Dim bmBitsPixel As Integer
    Dim bmBits As Long
End Structure


'Rectagle structure, needed to "build" the EMF
Private Structure RECT
    Dim Left As Long
    Dim Top As Long
    Dim Right As Long
    Dim Bottom As Long
End Structure


'API Functions for drawing graphics
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As _
  Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long,
  ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestDC As Long,
  ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long,
  ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long,
  ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As _
  Long
Private Declare Function GetObject Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetObjectA" (ByVal _
  hObject As Long, ByVal nCount As Long, lpObject As Object) As Long
Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long,
  ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long,
  ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long,
  ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, ByVal nSrcHeight As Long,
  ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long

'API Functions for creating metafiles
Private Declare Function CreateEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias _
  "CreateEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hdcRef As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String,
  lpRect As RECT, ByVal lpDescription As String) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As _
  Long
Private Declare Function DeleteEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hEmf As Long) As _
  Long
Private Declare Function SetMapMode Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long,
  ByVal nMapMode As Long) As Long


'This Enum is needed to set the "Mapping" property for EMF images
Public Enum MMETRIC
    MM_HIMETRIC = 3
    MM_LOMETRIC = 2
    MM_LOENGLISH = 4
    MM_ISOTROPIC = 7
    MM_HIENGLISH = 5
    MM_ANISOTROPIC = 8
    MM_ADLIB = 9
End Enum

'è una costante in decimale 13369370 
'https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/visualbasicexplorer/what-s-the-difference-vbsrccopy-or-t4443.html
Public Const vbSrcCopy = &HCC0020

' ==========================================

' This function creates an EMF image.
' Parameters:
'  SourceImage: Must be a picturebox
'  FileName: full pathname for Enhanced Metafile on disk
'  Metrics: a value from MMETRIC Enum
'  Comments (optional): You can add your own comments to an Enhanced Metafile
'
' Example:
'  Dim RetVal As Long
'  ' The best way for creating an EMF image is to use the MM_ADLIB mapping mode
'  RetVal = CreateEmf(Picture1, "image1.emf", MM_ADLIB,
' "Enhanced Metafile Demonstration Usage")

Public Function CreateEmf(ByRef SourceImage As Object, ByVal FileName As String,
  ByVal Metrics As MMETRIC, Optional ByVal Comments As String = Nothing) As Long
    'Variables and types
    Dim bm As BITMAP
    Dim hdcMem As Long   'Temporary Compatible Device Context


    Dim hdc As Long     'EMF Device Context
    Dim hEmf As Long    'Will get the returned value by CloseEnhMetafile API
    Dim R As RECT      'A rectangle that will enclose the EMF image
    Dim OldScale As Integer 'Used to maintain Picturebox ScaleMode property
    Dim HoldBitmap As Long 'Keeps the bitmap onto memory

    Comments = Comments & vbNullChar 'You can add comments to Metafiles. A NULL
    ' char is needed

    GetObject(SourceImage, Len(bm), bm) 'Reads image properties and puts them
    ' in a Bitmap structure

    R.Top = SourceImage.Top       'Creates a rectangle using bitmap
    ' properties
    R.Left = SourceImage.Left
    R.Right = SourceImage.Picture.Width
    R.Bottom = SourceImage.Picture.Height

    'Sets the Picturebox Scalemode properties to Pixels.
    OldScale = SourceImage.ScaleMode
    'SourceImage.ScaleMode = vbPixels   'commanetato perché è gia tutto in pixel

    'Creates the metafile to disk reading the picturebox device context thru
    ' the GetDC Api
    'FileName is a string containing the full pathname for the image
    'R is the rectangle structure as shown before
    'Some comments are added.
    hdc = CreateEnhMetaFile(SourceImage.hdc, FileName, R, Comments)

    '...sets the mapping property
    SetMapMode(hdc, Metrics)

    'Since Bitmap and Metafile are different, a new compatible device context
    ' must be created
    'with a reference to the EMF device context
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)

    'Takes the bitmap....
    HoldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, SourceImage)

    '...and copies first to intermediate device context reading data from the
    ' bitmap
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, SourceImage.ScaleWidth, SourceImage.ScaleHeight, SourceImage.hdc, 0, 0, vbSrcCopy)
    'and then to the EMF device context
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, SourceImage.ScaleWidth, SourceImage.ScaleHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, vbSrcCopy)

    'Reassigns bitmap previous value to DC before deleting
    SelectObject(hdcMem, HoldBitmap)
    'Next step is disposing objects
    DeleteDC(hdcMem)
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdcMem, SourceImage))

    'Closes the new metafile
    hEmf = CloseEnhMetaFile(hdc)

    If DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEmf) = 1 Then
        CreateEmf = 0  'No errors
    Else
        CreateEmf = 1  'If an error occurred,
        ' returns 1
    End If

    'sets the PictureBox Scalemode property to the previous mode
    SourceImage.ScaleMode = OldScale
    Return CreateEmf
End Function End Class
```