# Save metafile in C#

Tags: c#, wmf, .emf

If I have a wmf or emf image in System.Drawing.Image, is there a way to save the metafile data with c# without rendering it as a bitmap?  Calling Image.Save will render it to a bitmap and I want to keep the original data so that it would still be a valid .wmf or .emf format file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GDI+ / C#: How to save an image as EMF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can not.

On [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.aspx), it is stated:

**Remarks**

When you use the Save method to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file instead. This behavior occurs because the GDI+ component of the .NET Framework does not have an encoder that you can use to save files as .wmf or .emf files.

Comment: How to save it as PNG?

Answer (score 4):

Despite this MSDN page, it is possible to save a true EMF file. See this question: [gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf/895204#895204)

Comment: see the answer of user120789 in the link mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to save a metafile in its orignal format if you use the gdi32.dll.

I am using the method described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/12a1c749-b320-4ce9-aff7-9de0d7fd30ea/) and it works fine.