# Seemingly Easy .NET Import

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I need to call this method, but I can't find it in any namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx

It says it is in System.Windows.Forms namespace and in System.Windows.Forms.dll.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and imported the System.Windows.Forms reference into the project.

At the top I made an import (sry, my Java slang) `using FORMS = System.Windows.Forms;`

```
Graphics g = FORMS.CreateGraphics(); // error
```

Error is: "The type or namespace name 'CreateGraphics' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Thanks for any help.

---EDIT---

I am trying to run the code from the top answer from this post:

[GDI+ / C#: How to save an image as EMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf?tab=votes#tab-top)

---EDIT---

With a user's suggestions, I am trying:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();
FORMS.Control a = new FORMS.Control();
g = a.CreateGraphics();
```

---EDIT---

Never mind, sorry people, I am stupid. Will accept in a second.

Comment: That SO link you game assumes you are placing your code in a Form.

Comment: @Boo, oh leave it to me to not read it fully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
using FORMS = System.Windows.Forms;
```

Is a *namespace alias*, not a type alias.

Namespaces do not have methods defined on them.

Additionally, `CreateGraphics` is **not** static, so can't be called directly on a type either, only on an instance.

Assuming that `myForm` is an instance of [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx):

```
Graphics g = myForm.CreateGraphics();
```

In your linked example, `CreateGraphics()` is called on the `this` instance implicitly and assumes that the call is within a `Form` or `Control` type. So, if you are calling it within a control/form, it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

The Control class has a [CreateGraphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method. Therefore all controls have that method, which you can use to create a graphics context to draw on them.

```
Form frm = new Form();
Graphics g = frm.CreateGraphics();
//you use g to draw on your form frm
```

This is also what the **post you linked to says**.  See the comment :

```
var g = CreateGraphics(); // get a graphics object from your form, or wherever
```

[Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) also has an [FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) Method that returns a Graphics object to paint on an image.

Answer (score 0):

CreateGraphics is a method on System.Windows.Forms.Control

You would use it thusly:

//Create a control:
Panel panel = new Panel();

//Grab a graphics object from the control:
Graphics graphics = panel.CreateGraphics();

//Do something with your newly created Graphics object.