# How to convert an SVG file to an EMF file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, svg, .emf

It's definitely possible to convert an SVG to EMF, for example [this website](https://cloudconvert.org/svg-to-emf). I wonder if it's possible to achieve this conversion in C#?

---

**Update:**

I tried to read an SVG file using [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) and draw it to a `Graphics` object, then tried export the `Image` as a MetaFile in .emf extension (I followed the instruction here: [GDI+ / C#: How to save an image as EMF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf)). The reading was done successfully and the image did get exported as .emf. However, when I opened that .emf in PowerPoint, it couldn't be un-grouped, which indicated that the drawing info of that file was actually not dumped correctly.

**Update 2:**

Now it does export a ungroup-able .emf, but the ungrouping shows a really poor result. I used the following code to produce the .emf:

```
private void OpenPictureButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    _svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(openFileDialog.FileName);

    RenderSvg(_svgDoc);
}

private void SavePictureClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog {Filter = "Enhanced Meta File | *.Emf"};
    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    var path = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    var graphics = CreateGraphics();
    var img = new Metafile(path, graphics.GetHdc());
    var ig = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    _svgDoc.Draw(ig);

    ig.Dispose(); img.Dispose(); graphics.ReleaseHdc(); graphics.Dispose();
}

private void RenderSvg(SvgDocument svgDoc)
{
    svgImageBox.Image = svgDoc.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue but searching had no results.
Finally I ended up with my own simple solution below. I used [SVG.NET](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG).

```
public static byte[] ConvertToEmf(string svgImage)
{
    string emfTempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    try
    {
        var svg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgImage);
        using (Graphics bufferGraphics = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            using (var metafile = new Metafile(emfTempPath, bufferGraphics.GetHdc()))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile))
                {
                    svg.Draw(graphics);
                }
            }
        }

        return File.ReadAllBytes(emfTempPath);
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(emfTempPath);
    }
}
```

At first I create a temp file. Then I use `Draw(Graphics)` method to save emf in it. And at last I read bytes from temp file.
Don't try to use `MemoryStream` for `Metafile`. Unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: it has been around a year and finally :) I will try your solution and come back to you soon :)

Comment: Any idea how to do reverse? From .emf to .svg?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to be currently the best solution. This is almost like the accepted answer and uses [SVG.NET](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG), but is capable of doing it in memory.

The important changes are to release the handle and to reset the position memory stream.

```cs
public static Stream ConvertSvgToEmf(string svgImage)
{
    using var writeStream = new MemoryStream();

    var svg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgImage);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var sizedImage = new Bitmap((int)svg.Width.Value, (int)svg.Height.Value);
    using (var graphicsFromSizedImage = Graphics.FromImage(Image.FromHbitmap(sizedImage.GetHbitmap())))
    using (var metafile = new Metafile(stream, graphicsFromSizedImage.GetHdc(), EmfType.EmfPlusOnly)) // Specify EmfType for lesser file size
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(metafile))
    {
        svg.Draw(graphics);
        graphicsFromSizedImage.ReleaseHdc();
    }

    stream.Position = 0;

    return stream;
}
```

Be aware that the underlying implementation relies on `System.Drawing` and therefore the `gdi` must be accessible. On linux based OS's (or Docker images) `libgdiplus` must be installed.

As `System.Drawing` is considered to be [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-5.0#remarks), alternatives like [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) may be better suited for your case.