# Why is my EMF in Resources being converted to a bitmap?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why does an EMF called `blank.emf` in Resources end up saved as a bitmap?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Metafile emf = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.blank))
    {
        emf = new Metafile(ms);
    }
    emf.Save("C:\\Users\\chrisd\\Documents\\emfbitmap1.emf",
        ImageFormat.Emf);
}
```

`emfbitmap1.emf` is a bitmap, not EMF.  I am suspecting it is being converted to bitmap upon retrieval from Properties.Resources.  It is definitely an EMF on the file system.

Comment: How does it get form ths MemStream to the resources? How do you establish its type?

Comment: @bommelding The original EMF `blank.emf` was added to the project via Properties > Resources, where it was automatically assigned the name `blank`.  `Properties.Resources.blank` accesses this resource.  It is originally an EMF so its type should be `Metafile`.

Answer (score 0):

The EMF is being converted to a bitmap by the `Save` operation.

An EMF can be successfully written thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/733465/879601), with minor modifications.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

including in the class

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint GetEnhMetaFileBits(IntPtr hemf,
        uint cbBuffer, byte[] lpbBuffer);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool DeleteEnhMetaFile(IntPtr hemf);
```

and modifying the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Metafile emf = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.blank))
    {
        emf = new Metafile(ms);
    }

    IntPtr h = emf.GetHenhmetafile();
    uint size = GetEnhMetaFileBits(h, 0, null);
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    GetEnhMetaFileBits(h, size, data);
    using (FileStream w = File.
        Create("C:\\Users\\chrisd\\Documents\\emfbitmap1.emf"))
    {
        w.Write(data, 0, (int)size);
    }

    DeleteEnhMetaFile(h);
}
```

Of course, if it is not required to have the EMF in memory it can be written to disc directly.  E.g.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\chrisd\\Documents\\emfbitmap1.emf",
        Properties.Resources.blank);
}
```